# Can't get $view variable

Tags: php

I have a little problem, I can't get `$view` in included file. Please, help me, I don't know what I have to do. Tamplates are changing as shoud, because `else` condition is working good. `var_dump($view);` results:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: view in C:\xampp\htdocs\Accessories\adminpanel\tpl\main.php on line 26
NULL
```

index.php:

```
<?php    
    $view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'indexPage' : $_GET['view'];  

    switch ($view)
    {

    }

    if($view != "indexPage")
    {
        include "/tpl/main.php";
    }
    else
    {
        include "/tpl/indexPage.php";
    }
?>
```

main.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul id="category">
                <span>Hello, <?=$_SESSION['username'];?></span>
                <li><a href="?view=addItem">Add Item | </a></li>
                <li><a href="../lib/logout.php">Exit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article>
            <?php
                if(isset($view))
                {
                    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/adminpanel/tpl/pages/'. $view . '.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/adminpanel/tpl/pages/defaultPanel.php');
                }
                // var_dump($view);
            ?>    
        </article>    
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I used same thing, when wrote another website It Worked:
index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'catalog.php';

    $view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'generalPage' : $_GET['view'];
    $cat_name = empty($_GET['cat_name']) ? '' : $_GET['cat_name'];

    switch ($view)
    {
        case('generalPage'):
            $rand_goods = get_random_good();
            break;
        case('categoryPage'):
            if ($ids) $products = get_products($ids);
            else $products = null;
            break;
        case('productPage'):
            $product = $get_one_product;
            break;
    }

    switch ($cat_name)
    {
        case('about'):
            $about = get_about();
            break;
    }

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/tpl/main.php');    
?>
```

main.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accessories</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header></header>    
        <div id="breadCrumbs">
            <?= $breadcrumbs; ?>
        </div>    
        <nav>
            <ul class="category">
                <li><a href="index.php">General</a></li>
                <?php echo $categories_menu; ?>
        </nav>

        <article>
            <?php
                if ($cat_name == '')
                    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/tpl/pages/' . $view . '.php');
                else 
                {
                    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/tpl/pages/' . $cat_name . 'Page.php');
                }
            ?>
        </article>
        <div class="clear"></div>    
        <footer>
            <p id="copy">&copy 2014</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".category").dcAccordion();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No sure, but I think you need to save the view variable to your session. In your index.php file.

Comment: You have not set a value for $view in your main.php page. Either you do this by sending it with GET like you did on page index.php. Or you save it in a session like you are doing on main.php. On page index.php start session and then assign the variable from get to the session. `$_SESSION['View'] = $_GET['view'];` Then on main.php you retrieve the value from the session.

Comment: If I will use `$_GET['view']` it will work, I know, but when I will use `switch-case`  `cases` will not work. UPDATED question

Comment: I don't understand this part: `switch ($view) { }` You have nothing defined in this switch.

Comment: yeah, I haven't done anything yet. It's just empty right now.

Comment: What is it you like to achieve? Maybe the logic of you IF statement is not doing what you like to achieve.

Comment: which file are you talking about? `main.php` or `index.php`

Comment: B.T.W. you might need to close the line in the `switch ($view) { ; }`. Or comment this line out.

Comment: commented,nothing changed

Comment: If you change `$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'indexPage' : $_GET['view'];` into  `$view = isset ($_GET['view']);` does this give you the desired result?

Comment: No, didn't give. I'm using IF statement , bacause i don't have view on index and main pages.

Comment: In words: You like to include main.php if the variable view is not indexPage and include indexPage when view is indexPage.

Comment: If that is the case I think you need to start session on index.php, because a session need to initiated on the first line.

Comment: Yes. Main idea is as you told.And it's working right now. Problem is when main.php have been included. I need to get file name from view to  create path to page file which should be included between `<article></article>`,but `$view == NULL` in main.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of your variable $view.

Try this:

index.php

```
<?php    
    $view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'indexPage' : $_GET['view'];  



    if($view != "indexPage")
    {
        include "/tpl/main.php";
    }
    else
    {
        include "/tpl/indexPage.php";
    }
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul id="category">
            <span>Hello, <?=$_SESSION['username'];?></span>
            <li><a href="?view=addItem">Add Item | </a></li>
            <li><a href="../lib/logout.php">Exit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
            <?php
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            if(isset($view)){
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/adminpanel/tpl/pages/'. $view . '.php');
            }else{
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Accessories/adminpanel/tpl/pages/defaultPanel.php');
            }
           echo var_dump($view);
            ?>

    </article>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, it's working and I knew it, but I didn't want to use it, because as in my sample (UPDATED part) I shouldn't insert `$view = $_GET['view'];`... Ok, thank You, man.